# website times out when i try to access it

Tags: url, dns

when i try to go to the url of my site i get page cannot be displayed. i can open the site on the server when i log onto it through remote desktop, but on my laptop pinging in through cmd shows a time out error. ive tried reseting iis, recycling the app pool and stopping and starting the site. what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

From the little information you have written here: maybe there is a firewall on your server running (as most of Linux distros install one) and your HTTP port and ICMP echo reply (ping) are not allowed to go thru.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your firewall is blocking your site. Ensure that port 80 is open in your firewall.

Comment: i tried turning windows firewall off and the site now works. ive never had to do anything with windows firewall before so im not sure where to allow access to this site. there are multiple sites running on this server, 4 of them sharing the same ip. all the other sites worked fine so port 80 must be fine, what could it be on the firewall thats preventing this domain?

Comment: WEIRD!!! I turned the firewall back on (not changed any settings) and i can still access the site??!?! im confused.